# Get intersecting rows based on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table in SQL Server.This is how data is stored currently in table:

[image: table data]

I want to get all **common menu_id** when **multiple role_id** are provided.
For eg: I want **menu_id 1**  when role_id provided are 1 and 3 as menu_id 1 is common for all role_id specified. I have no clue what query should I use. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be me, but that statement makes no sense. What is your question here (you've only told us what you want, not asked anything). What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work? What are your expected results?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data - _and the expected result_ - as formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `menu_id`s that have a list of `role_id` values.  This should do what you want:

```
select menu_id
from t
where role_id in (1, 3)
group by menu_id
having count(*) = 2;  -- number of values in IN list
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b1497c80bb524fb0513e9a5818c6694) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

use `group by` with `having`

```
select menu_id from tablename
group by menu_id
having count(distinct role_id)>1
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, you just missed the requirement for selecting particular role ids. Just add `where role_id in (1,3)` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87764/2

Comment: No need to use `distinct`, it's likely that the table is properly designed, that is role_id + menu_id composite has unique/primary key. Say on a given menu_id of 42, there would be no repeating role_id for it, the table would not have these repeating values (7, 42), (7, 42). So there, `distinct` is not needed